# Trying to install python libraries(pywin32) on system having no internet access

Tags: python, installation, pywin32

I downloaded various packages via pip install on the machine with internet access , then copied files from site packages to the server with no internet access.

But even then I am getting error from pywin32 library that

import error : no module named win32api.com

this module is imported as part of **init**.py file - in win32com site packages

Same packages and libraries are working fine for system having internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Download the matching `.wheel` and install it on your system that is offline.
[pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files)

Attention: The `wheels` are for cpython.

You can also `pip download` your package and install it everywhere. [download commands](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/)